# Is the story of Gajendra-Mokṣa mentioned in other texts besides the Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam Purāṇa?

Tags: scripture, vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana, moksha, animals

We find the complete story of the Elephant named - Gajendra getting Mokṣa through god Viṣṇu's grace, (and hence the reason for calling it the 'Gajendra Mokṣa'),  in Chapter [2](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/2/), [3](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/3/) & [4](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/4/) of the [Canto 8](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/) of the Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam Purāṇa.

#### Do other scriptures too, mention the story of Gajendra Mokṣa?

In which other scriptures besides the Bhāgavata Mahā-Purāṇa, is the story of  Gajendra Mokṣa found?

---

One short reference is found in the  Skanda Purāṇa, but I'm looking for the complete story like the Bhāgavatam, if any:

> [Verse 2.4.25.21](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/skanda-purana-sanskrit/d/doc750115.html)
>
> ग्राहग्रस्तो हि नागेंद्रो यन्नामस्मरणात्पुरा ।
> विमुक्तः संनिधिं प्राप्तो जातोऽयं जयसंज्ञकः ॥ २१ ॥
>
> > 21. The great elephant who had been caught in the jaws of a crocodile, became liberated formerly by remembering his name. He reached the presence of Viṣṇu and has become (the attendant) named Jaya.
>
> [Chapter 25](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371667.html#note-t-139469), Section 4 - Kārttikamāsa-māhātmya

Answer (score 5):

The complete episode of the Gajendra Mokṣa is also found in the Vāmana Purāṇa.

The same may be accessed from the Archive site, as follows:-

> English Translation - [Chapter 58](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.313087/page/468/mode/1up?view=theater)
>
> Hindi Translation - [Chapter 84](https://archive.org/details/vaman-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n421/mode/1up?view=theater)